# Eslint: --fix not resolving warnings according to .eslintrc rules

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint

I am trying to auto-fix issues in my js file using

```
eslint --fix -c "/path/to/.eslintrc" <file-name.js>
```

but with no success.
Went through [Eslint Rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/).
I have to fix "no-undef" & "no-unused-vars" using the command, but it still not works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ESLint `--fix` will fix everything that it  **can**  fix, but in many cases won't be able to automatically follow every rule.

Rules that can be taken care of with `--fix` can be found in the [rules documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) - they'll have a wrench icon next to the rule name.

Looks like the `no-undef` and `no-unused-vars` rules don't, so you'll have to manually comb through the warnings and manually modify the code.

Comment: Ok, got your point, I guess I will have to check other rules to implement --fix automatically.